# Spring register all beans with a given name pattern as beans

Tags: spring

I want to register all public classes whose names end in `ApplicationService` as if they were annotated with `@Service` and `@Transactional` annotations.

How can I achieve this in Spring 5 without spring boot.

Comment: Use component-scanning with a filter.

Comment: component scan instantiates annotated classes, I want it to instantiate classes with names matching a criteria. if you have a working configuration add an answer please.

Comment: No it doesn't only do that. You can use a pattern filter as well, please read the documentation instead of jumping to conclusion with wrong/flawed understanding of technologies in use. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/FilterType.html for supported filter tpes, by default the annotation ones are enabled. You can write your own regex or aspecjt one (or provide a custom implementation) to detect classes that match that pattern.